# Probability involving exponentially distributed random variabl

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Two buses A and B arrive independently at a bus station at random rate of 5/hour and 4/hour respectively. A passenger comes to the bus station at 10 am. What is the probability that it takes at most 5 minutes before the first bus arrives at the station?

*Attempt*

Let X and Y be random variables indicating time of arrivals of Bus A and B respectively. Then, X and Y are exponentially distributed random variables with rate 5 and 4 respectively.
So the probability density functions of X and Y are 5*exp(-5*t) and 4*exp(-4*t).

Now, let Z = min(X,Y) be a new random variable. Then,
I need to calculate P(Z<5/60).

Question:
My solution sheet goes as follows:
P(Z<5/60) = 1-P(Z>5/60) = 1-P(X>5/60, Y>5/60) 
and goes on like this. 
But why cannot I just calculate P(Z<5/60) = P(X<5/60, Y<5/60) directly? These two give me different answers, meaning my attempt might be wrong. Why do we need to calculate the complementary probability?

Comment: It does not matter if the second bus arrives before 5 minutes if the first one does arrive in 5 minutes. You only care about the complement of the event that no busses arrive within 5 minutes.

Comment: I did not get it. @TimDikland

Comment: There are four possible interesting events. P(X<5, Y<5), P(X<5, Y>5), P(X>5, Y<5), P(X>5, Y<5). Now ask yourself which of those events are desirable and which are not. (Here X<5 means bus X arrives within 5 minutes)

Comment: I am still confused. So, if the question was: What is the probability that she waits at least 5 mins before the first bus arrives? Would I directly calculate P(Z>5/60) = P(X>5/60,Y>5/60)?

Comment: Exactly. Your mistake in your first calculation is that $P(Z < 5/60) \neq P(X<5/60,Y<5/60)$. If you would do it correctly then you would find that $P(Z<5/60) = P(X<5/60, Y<5/60) + P(X<5/60, Y>5/60) + P(X>5/60, Y<5/60)$, which is obviously more work to calculate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another interesting way to approach this problem. I'll start out with a more general version, and then we'll look at the case you need.

Let $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_n$ be *independent* and let $X_{(1)}$ be the minimum observation. Let's find the CDF of $X_{(1)}$.

\begin{align*}
F_1(x) &= P(X_{(1)} \leq x) & \text{(definition)} \\
&= 1 - P(X_{(1)} > x) & \text{(complement)} \\
&= 1 - P(X_1 > x, \ X_2 > x, \ \cdots, \ X_n > x) & \text{(min > x $\Leftrightarrow$ all > x)} \\
&= 1 - P(X_1 > x)P(X_2 > x)\cdots P(X_n > x) & \text{(independence)} \\
\end{align*}

### Back to the problem

Let
$$X \sim Exp(4) \quad Y \sim Exp(5) \quad Z = min(X, Y)$$
$$P(X > x) = e^{-4x}$$ 
$$P(Y > x) = e^{-5x}$$
Hence, by the above result we can write the CDF of the minimum as:
$$P(Z \leq x) = 1 - e^{-4x}e^{-5x} = 1 - e^{-9x}$$

Now you can calculate the desired probability easily.

Note that this is equivalent mathematically to the approach that Davis gives, **but** with this approach we see that the the minimum of independent exponential random variables is itself Exponentially distributed! Specifically, $Z \sim Exp(4+5)$.

Answer (score 0):

$Z < \frac{5}{60}$ might occur without $X < \frac{5}{60}$ occurring, specifically, if $Y < \frac{5}{60}$.

Multiplying probabilities of independent events gives you the probability of their intersection (both events happen), but what you want is the probability of their union. Call $E$ the event that bus A arrives before the given time, and $F$ the event that bus B arrives before the given time. Then, the event you are interested in is:

$E \cup F = (E^c \cap F^c)^c$

The equality is by DeMorgan's law. Now you can figure out the probability by multiplying the probabilities of $E^c$ and $F^c$.